# Mirror an exiting android application in Android Auto

Tags: android, android-auto

I'm trying to figure what needs to be done in order to let my users use my existing app in Android auto,c
I have a navigation app that works only on Android devices. now I want to enable my users to mirror the exiting app on their android Auto devices. from the Android Auto docs, it seems that I need to reimplement the app and fit it to the Android Auto os. Is this really the process? Is there any option just to mirroring my app on the Android auto screen?

https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps/auto

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unfortunately No,** You cannot mirror an existing Android App. You have found the correct *documentation* on how to make Android App compatible with Android Auto. You have to follow the steps and perform the retrofit procedure.
It should not take long though.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the help... so i will have to implement all the UI logic again? all the screens i have in my mobile app should be reimplemented using the Android auto SDK?

Comment: @c.o Sadly yes until Google comes up with some convenient method in the future. Please accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!